# Does MiniProfiler work in ASP.NET MVC2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, mvc-mini-profiler

Does The StackExchange MiniProfiler http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/ work in ASP.NET MVC2?  If so, how?  When adding MiniProfiler to the project, what is the MVC2 equivalent of:

```
@MvcMiniProfiler.MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. See the FAQ: http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

That is the razor syntax. The equivalent for Web Forms is

```
<%: MvcMiniProfiler.MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes() %>
```

Comment: Thanks - I've got it the RenderIncludes() working now.  But it does not show the little box in the corner showing the results.  I see that MiniProfiler uses jquery 1.61. - I still use 1.4.2, do I need to upgrade?

Comment: Miniprofiler installed now thanks.  The main problem I had was that MP requires EntityFramework 4.1 when I had 4.0, so just had to do a quick EF upgrade first.